# How to sum one column based on another column

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, aggregate, analysis

this is my first post so please excuse any irregularities. I am working on textual analysis with R and am currently trying to sum up the columns of my data frame conditioned on another column. Specifically, my results 'dfResults' looks as follows:

[dfResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNj0l.png)

I want to count the word frequencies for all positive words (1) and separately the frequencies of all negative words (-1) so that I can easily calculate the sentiment score. This is probably very easy, but I tried the aggregate and sum functions and it did not work. Would appreciate the help!

Comment: group by `sentiment` and then sum freq

Comment: Please Show your Code and data set which you write in R.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this is what you want :

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(sentiment) %>% summarise(x = sum(freq))
```

Answer (score -1):

Both the above answers will work. Additionally, if you want to do it without using any library, the base way, then you have at least two options

1. `split()` the data and sum the resulting lists with lapply/sapply, OR
2. `use aggregate()`

```r
  lapply ( ( split(df$freq,df$sentiment) ), sum)    
  aggregate(df$freq, by=list(df$sentiment), FUN=sum)
```

Edit/Correction - `aggregate` is not from base but from the `stats` package. However, given that `stats` too is one of the default packages, it is available in the R session.